# How do I make a line within alignat free of alignment restriction?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, alignat

the `independant line` has affected the 2nd align symbol `&&`, how do I disable it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
    &\alpha &&:= 0\\
    &\text{independant line}\\
    &\beta &&:= 1\\
    &\text{random line}\\
    &\sigma &&:= 2\\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you want that line to be handled?  Centered? Left aligned?

Comment: How about `\intertext{random line}`?  It will be set as text, not math, though.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I hope the line to be Left aligned, if possible.

Comment: Left aligned to the margin? Oor left aligned to the other variables (which are not actually left aligned, because of the way `alignat` works?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes updated.

Comment: Replace `\text` with `\rlap`

Comment: pedantic niggle: the spelling is "independent", not "independant".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `\text` with `\rlap`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
    &\alpha &&:= 0\\
    &\rlap{independant line with some $\alpha$ mathematics notation}\\
    &\beta &&:= 1\\
    &\rlap{random line}\\
    &\sigma &&:= 2\\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with `\rlap` can I have any mathematics notation?

Comment: @Wentao You can use `$` delimiters inside the `\rlap`, just as you would inside of `\text`.  One difference that I don't think affects you is that `\text` preserves the current mathstyle font size (e.g., script sizes), whereas `\rlap` does not.